# Как работать с GULP?

Tags: gulp

После работы с GULP (компиляция файлов SASS, настройка Browser-Sync, Bower, сбор и минимализация CSS и JS файлов), что нужно делать на выходе? Нужно ли все стандартные файлы GULP (`package.json`, `gulpfile.js` и т.д.) заливать на хостинг или они нужны были только при работе?

Comment: Не нужно. Что собралось и минимализировалось — то и пользуйте

Comment: Понятно, очень вам благодарен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сервер идет лишь ваш проект. Файлы gulp это сборщик и на проект не идет. И когда будете заливать в репозиторий, то скидывайте только package.json, gulpfile.js. А затем просто подкачивайте файлы с помощью

> npm install

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо вам большое)